# Native linking failed - Xamarin For Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build an iOS app on windows visual studio using Xamarin For Visual Studio Trial. When compiling I am getting this error:

Error   136 MT5201:Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-L/Users/brandon/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iCropTrak_vsios/9bc8504a-65b2-484f-b71c-1d0cb02d21f6" "-lgdal_x86" "-lc3dsqlite3" "-lstdc++" "-all_load" [K:\Development\AZSim\Products\CropTrak\iCropTrak_vsios.csproj]
        0   0

It compiles fine on the mac - but having trouble getting it going with the windows version. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `{ProjectDir}` in your project options ? If so you might be running into a current [limitation](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2025/linker-error-linking-with-an-external-a-lib#latest) where the directories won't match between platforms.

You should be able to workaround it, either by replacing `{ProjectDir}` or **much better** by [using](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/5371/#Comment_5371) the `[LinkWith]` attribute.

Comment: I feel like I may be getting somewhere - using the LinkWith attribute I am now getting this: MT5202:Native linking failed... Reviewing the build Log I see this: ld: file not found: /var/folders/48/lwbyycsx36jgjpghzg93r5wr0000gn/T/tmp4a6c874.tmp/libgdal_x86.a

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle the Native reference inside a dll.

Take a look on this: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/5371/#Comment_5371

and this:

https://github.com/viniciusjarina/NativeBindingVS

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

we discover this issue like two weeks ago, this only happens in simulator AFAIK. Seems that the dependency LevelDB left their Main symbol. I'll file a bug on Firebase. The workaround for this is to change the behavior of the **Registrar** on Simulator:

1. Open your project settings
2. Go to **Build** tab
3. Select **iOS Build** option
4. Type `--registrar:static` in **Additional mtouch arguments** textbox
5. Click on **Ok**

Don't forget to add this in **Release** and **Debug** configuration of **iPhoneSimulator** platform.

Answer (score 0):

when i checked the [source](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents) of the packages i found that they relies on

```
Xamarin.Build.Download
```

when i install the package problem resolved .